# WCF: Cannot open channel between client and server using netTCPBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, client-server, communicationexception

I have a client/server application using WCF. When opening a channel between my machine and a server from another domain, the following SecurityNegociationException is raised:

Either the target name is incorrect or the server has rejected the client credentials.

And that only started a couple of days ago. It had been working before, and still works from another machine with the same credentials.
I'm suspecting files in the AppData folder, but i still have no idea what it could be.

Does anyone please have an idea about how to solve this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the solution. I tried to connect to the server, and, as always, i got the error, so i checked the Event Viewer and found this:

> "The password stored in Credential Manager is invalid. This might be
>   caused by the user changing the password from this computer or a
>   different computer. To resolve this error, open Credential Manager in
>   Control Panel, and reenter the password for the [Login] credentials."

I changed the stored server password in Credential Manager, and now it works.